# Django: CSS Background image not working after update

Tags: python, css, django, upgrade

**I just upgraded my Django 1.10 (Python 3.5) app to Django 1.11 (Python 3.6)**. Most things still work, but for some reason my CSS background images are not being rendered anymore (I tried with the old version and it still works there). This is only happening for CSS, it still loads normally when it is a HTML tag.

This is the first time there I am dealing with an update for my Django app, so I'm not so sure about what is the right way dealing with those minor issues.

**I've been trying different approaches for the background image, but none of them worked.**

Here is my failing code,

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block style %}
<style>

#top {
    /*background: url("{% static 'img/skyscraper.jpg' %}") no-repeat center center fixed;*/
    background: url("/static/img/skyscraper.jpg");
    /*background: url('{{ STATIC_URL }}img/skyscraper.jpg');*/
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 700px;
}

</style>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute `python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: I tried and realized that maybe the problem was python 3.6.
According to the ReadMe file of python 3.6 something changed regarding the SSL connection. I'll make a new question about it.
Thanks.

Comment: So far it seems the problem was really caused by Python 3.6 and the fact that I'm using AWS S3.